# Calling the exit function in Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sys

e = input("Do you want to continue?(Enter Y or N)?")
if e == "Y":
    sys.exit()
```

I'm trying to create an exit function that allows the user to exit. Am I using the wrong format or did I mess up the syntax ?

Comment: indentation is wrong

Comment: run the edited version -)) this should work

Comment: @marmeladze now the question is confusing though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import sys

e = input("Do you want to continue?(Enter Y or N)?")
if e == "Y":
    sys.exit()
```

There was an indentation problem and you were missing a `:`

Also, I'd like to recommend using this logic also:

```
import sys

e = input("Do you want to continue?(Enter Y or N)?")
if e.lower() in  {'y','yes'}:
    sys.exit()
```

This will provide more flexibility since it will accept `Y`, `y` and different versions of `yes`.